# Types of property 'XXXX' are incompatible

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma

I am currently using nest js with prisma as orm.

My problem occurs at the time of update , I have the following error the error is recurrent on all the entities which have a relationship with another. only in update.:

```
TS2322: Type 'UpdateMarketDto' is not assignable to type '(Without<MarketsUpdateInput, MarketsUncheckedUpdateInput> & MarketsUncheckedUpdateInput) | (Without<...> & MarketsUpdateInput)'.   Type 'UpdateMarketDto' is not assignable to type 'Without<MarketsUncheckedUpdateInput, MarketsUpdateInput> & MarketsUpdateInput'.     Types of property 'univer' are incompatible.       Type 'CreateUniverDto | UpdateUniverDto' is not assignable to type 'UniversUpdateOneRequiredWithoutMarketsNestedInput'.         Type 'CreateUniverDto' has no properties in common with type 'UniversUpdateOneRequiredWithoutMarketsNestedInput'.
```

This is the endpoint :

```
update(id: number, updateMarketDto: UpdateMarketDto) {
    return this.prisma.markets.update({
      where: { id },
      data: updateMarketDto,
    });
  }
```

This is the createDTO :

```
export class CreateMarketDto {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'Femme' })
  @IsString()
  @IsDefined()
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty({ example: 'textile.png' })
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  icon: string;

  @ApiProperty({ example: 'true' })
  @IsBoolean()
  isActive: boolean;

  @ApiProperty({ example: '3' })
  @IsOptional()
  univer: CreateUniverDto | UpdateUniverDto;
}
```

This is the updateDTO :

```
export class UpdateMarketDto extends PartialType(CreateMarketDto) {}
```

This is prisma model :

```
model Univers {
    id  Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
    name String
    icon String?
    isActive Boolean    @default(false)
    markets Markets[]
}

model Markets {
    id  Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
    name String
    icon String?
    isActive Boolean    @default(false)
    univer Univers @relation(fields:[univerId], references: [id])
    univerId Int
    categories Categories[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted looks like a TypeScript error, so it shouldn't actually stop the update from happening unless the error is stopping the server from running.

The error is pretty descriptive -

`Type 'CreateUniverDto' has no properties in common with type 'UniversUpdateOneRequiredWithoutMarketsNestedInput'.`

Whatever type `CreateUniverDto` is, it's not compatible with Prisma's `UniversUpdateOneRequiredWithoutMarketsNestedInput` type. If you're confident that these two types are indeed identical, you can cast it as the desired type:

```
update(id: number, updateMarketDto: UpdateMarketDto) {
  return this.prisma.markets.update({
    where: { id },  
    data: updateMarketDto as Prisma.UniversUpdateOneRequiredWithoutMarketsNestedInput,
  });
}
```

You should inspect the `Prisma.UniversUpdateOneRequiredWithoutMarketsNestedInput` to make sure that its type is exactly what you're passing as `updateMarketDto`, otherwise the update will fail.

If the two types do not overlap, you need to then provide them to Prisma manually:

```
update(id: number, updateMarketDto: UpdateMarketDto) {
  return this.prisma.markets.update({
    where: { id },  
    data: {
      isActive: {
        set: updateMarketDto.isActive
      },
      name: {
        set: updateMarketDto.name
      },
      // add other fields here based on where they live in updateMarketDto
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: what you are telling me is correct, however the problem comes from my relationship. updateMarketDto contains univer (which is my relation with the Universe table) normally during an edition my updateMarketDto object contains the univer object. Do you understand my problem? I can't solve this typing error my UpdateMarketDto inherits from CreateMarketDto

Comment: If the two types truly have no overlap, you need to provide the options to the `data` option on `markets.update.data`. I expanded on my original post to clarify how you would do that. Check out Prisma's docs on the subject: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#update

Comment: the error is indeed a problem of the type the concern I "can't find a way to fix it with the way you showed me. So I did a test that solves my problem temporarily by
change the type in the dto to any

Answer (score 0):

You have to update data for nested property separately like:

```js
update(id: number, updateMarketDto: UpdateMarketDto) {
    return this.prisma.markets.update({
      where: { id },
      data: {
        ...updateMarketDto,
        univer:{
            update: {
                ...updateMarketDto.univer
            }
        }
        },
    });
  }
```